# Can an Embedded .swf Change Variables in a Parent Project?

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2

I have a Flash project (`main.swf`) that opens another .swf inside it via a button press:

```
my_btn.onRelease = function() {
    loadMovie("otherFile.swf", "_level1");
};
```

How do I get `otherFile.swf` to alter variables within `main.swf`?

I'm using Flash Player 10 and ActionScript 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, do not use levels. Instead, load into a movieclip. If you *must* use levels, your main SWF is in _level0.

If you load into a movieclip you can think of the loaded SWF as just being the content of that movieclip, so if, in the loaded clip, you refer to _parent then you are talking to the parent of the container movieclip.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be looking for fscommand.  That may do what you need.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary372.html